# BeautifulSoup returns noneType

Tags: python, xml, xbrl

I am trying to use the following Python code to get some data from EDGAR database.

```
html1 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019317000070/aapl-20170930.xml'
xbrl_resp = requests.get(html1)
xbrl_str = xbrl_resp.text
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(xbrl_str, 'lxml')
mytag = soup1.find('us-gaap:StockholdersEquity',{'contextRef':'FI2017Q4'})
print(mytag)
```

It returns none even though the tag exists in the xml file. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues that you are running into to. First, pass through the content of the request rather than the text. Second, use the xml parser instead of the lxml parser. Finally, you're incorrectly searching within the 'us-gaap:StockholdersEquity' tag.

```
html1 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019317000070/aapl-20170930.xml'
xbrl_resp = requests.get(html1)
xbrl_str = xbrl_resp.content
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(xbrl_str, 'xml')
mytag = soup1.find('us-gaap:StockholdersEquity',contextRef='FI2017Q4')
print(mytag)
```

Comment: I tried this code and it worked. Thanks Btw: soup = BeautifulSoup(xbrl_str, 'lxml')
tag_list = soup.find_all()
for tag in tag_list:
    if tag.name == 'us-gaap:stockholdersequity':
        if tag.attrs['contextref'] == 'FI2017Q4':
            print(tag.text)

Answer (score 0):

The XML Parser converts the xml tags to lowercase: see here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml. Therefore you need to search with lowercase names, such as:

```
     mytag = soup1.find('us-gaap:stockholdersequity',contextref='FI2017Q4')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of `soup.find('table')` returning `None`.
This issue occurred in an environment where the lxml package version was 3.4.4.

On another environment with lxml version 3.7.3 the same code worked fine.

So, I went back to the 'bad' environment and upgraded the lxml package version.

```
pip install lxml --upgrade
```

`soup.find('table')` started working after that.

Hope this helps!

Ram